# Call function with (unknown) variable number of parameters?

Tags: php, function, variadic

I'm need to send params to the function

```
array_intersect_key()
```

but sometimes i'm need to send 2 arrays, sometimes - 3 or more:

```
array_intersect_key($arr_1, $arr_2);
OR
array_intersect_key($arr_1, $arr_2, $arr_3, $arr_4);
```

Comment: If I understand your question, you've answered it already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you want to create your own function like this, the key is to use `func_get_args()`:

```
function mumble(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach ($args as $arg){
        ... whatever
    }
}
```

If you just want to call it with multiple args, either "just do it", or use `call_user_func_array()`:

```
$args = array();
... append args to $args
call_user_func_array('array_intersect_key', $args);
```

Comment: I've never encountered this function before and I feel like I should have a very long time ago -- thank you so much for brining it to my attention!

Answer (score 0):

```
call_user_func_array('foo', array('foo', 'bar', 'foo N'));

function foo($param1, $param2, $paramN) {
    // TADÁÁÁ
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the [func_get_args() method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) for handling this; something like:

```
function my_function() {
    $numArgs=func_num_args();
    if($numArgs>0) {
        $argList=func_get_args();
        for($i=0;$i<$numArgs;$i++) {
            // Do stuff with the argument here
            $currentArg=$argList[$i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the http://php.net site first before asking about the standard functions, because you get all your questions answered there itself.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.funchand.php

I got your question, here is one way you can do that :

```
$arr_of_arr = array($arr1, $arr2, $arr3, ..., $arrn);
```

or

```
$arr_of_arr = func_get_args();

if(count($arr_of_arr) > 1){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr_of_arr) - 1; $i++){
        if(! $i){
            $intersec = array_intersect_key($arr_of_arr[0], $arr_of_arr[1]);
            $i = 2;
        }
        else{
            $intersec = array_intersect_key($intersec, $arr_of_arr[$i++]);
        }
    }
}
```

`$intersec` would now contain the intersection.

Comment: Please expand on the links and how they relate to the question. A small example goes a long ways to increase the quality of a response.

Comment: @pst Sorry for that answer. Code now added.

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    echo "Number of arguments: $numargs<br />";
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    foreach($arg_list  as $arg) {
        if(is_array($arg)) print_r($arg)."<br />";  
        else echo "<br />".$arg;
    }
}

foo(array(1,2,3), 2, 3);
```

Answer (score -1):

The `array_intersect_key`has already a protoype allowing multiple inputs :

```
array array_intersect_key ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $ ... ] )
```

So I don't really see the issue there.

Comment: The issue is "how to call it with N inputs"?

Comment: array_intersect_key ( $array1 , $array2, $array3, ...,$arrayN);

Comment: This answer does not deal with the fact that the OP will not have prior knowledge (programmatically) of how many arguments will be passed to `array_intersect_key()`.  You don't see the issue because you misunderstand that the question is asking about writing a variadic function.  Downvote, because this answer is not helpful.