# Java "String... someStrings" equivalent in PHP

Tags: php, parameters

i was wondering if there is a "String...stringArray" equivalent in PHP, something that  can build an array based on "stringArray" parameters, i.e.

Java:

```
public void method1(){
    int aNumber = 4;
    String string1 = "first string";
    String string2 = "second string";
    String string3 = "third string";

    processStrings(aNumber, string1, string2, string3);
    /*
       string1, string2 and string3 will become b = {string1, string2, string3}
       in function "processStrings"
    */
}

public void processStrings(int a, String...b){
    System.out.println(b[0]); //in this case it will print out "first string"
    System.out.println(b[1]); //in this case it will print out "second string"
    System.out.println(b[2]); //in this case it will print out "third string"
}
```

Is there a way to do the same thing with PHP?

I know i can use

```
function processStrings($a, $b){}
```

and then call it like this

```
function method1(){
    $myInt = 4;
    $strings = array("first string","second string","third string");
    processStrings($myInt, $strings);
}
```

But i would like to know if there is a way to pass an undefined number of parameters like i do with Java

Comment: You have over a thousand reputation. I'm sure you can think of a better title for your question.

Comment: There is a question related to yours, did you see it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128477/call-function-with-unknown-variable-number-of-parameters

Comment: @GökhanÇoban No i didn't see it, however i need my function to require at least 2 parameters (possibly without having to manually check if func_num_args>=2)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From php manual: [func_get_args()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    echo "Number of arguments: $numargs<br />\n";
    if ($numargs >= 2) {
        echo "Second argument is: " . func_get_arg(1) . "<br />\n";
    }
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "<br />\n";
    }
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
?>
```

While you can do it, i offer not to define any arguments in your function, because it gets very confusing when any of the defined arguments are omitted.

Comment: And what if it is required to have at least 2 parameters? i.e. `function1($a,$b [,$c...])` How can i do it (possibly without having to manually check if `func_num_args>=2`)?

Comment: You can define arguments as i didn't offer in my answer. You should know that func_get_args() will give all of the arguments as array.

Comment: There is no exact equivalent in php like your usage.